# Fixed gutter width with susy

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-compass, susy-sass

I found an example here about fixed gutters (http://sassmeister.com/gist/7da95c41fff076dd7266) and first it looked really simple:

```
$susy: (
  gutter-position: inside-static,
  container: 100%,
  columns: 4,
  column-width: 120px,
  gutter: 15px/120px,
  debug: (
    image: show,
  ),
);
```

I thought I only need to change the 15px to anything and it will be fine.. but it's not. I tried to change it, but no result. I tried to search on the official website, but I didn't find anything about `gutter`, only about `gutters`. What is the difference? How does the gutter work?

I would like columns with percentages, but with fixed 25px padding.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `gutter` setting. You need to use `gutters`. Everything else here looks good.